# Check if an array contains all the elements of an array that is nested

Tags: javascript

I will have 2 arrays as follows. *combosArr* is a 2D array and *arr1* is an array of integers

```
let combosArr = [[1,2,3], [3,6,9]];
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; // return [1,2,3]
```

I want the checker function to return me the elements (which is an array) of `combosArr` if every integer of that element is present in the `arr1`.
I tried the following code which didn't work for me.

```
let checker = (compareThis, combos) => {
    combos.some(array => {
        array.every(e => {
            if (compareThis.includes(e)) console.log(array);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
let combosArr = [[1,6,7], [1,2]];
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

let checker = (compareThis, combos) => {
    combos.forEach(array => {
        const isP = (e) => arr1.includes(e);
        const isPresent = array.every(isP);
        if (isPresent) console.log(array);
   });
}
```

This will give you 2 separate arrays as follows:

```
[1,6,7] [1,2]
```

Or you can have a single array with the following code:

```
let combosArr = [[1,6,7], [1,2]];
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let finalArray = [];

let checker = (compareThis, combos) => {
    combos.forEach(array => {
        const isP = (e) => arr1.includes(e);
        const isPresent = array.every(isP);
        if (isPresent) finalArray.push(array);
    });
    console.log(finalArray)
}
```

This will give you one single array as

```
[1,6,7,1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code makes the trick:

```
let combosArr = [[1,2,3], [3,6,7]];
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

combosArr.forEach(e => {
if(e.every(r => arr1.includes(r)))
  console.log(e);
})
```

Or the following, for printing something JUST if all elements of both arrays in combosArr contains elements of arr1:

```
let combosArr = [[1,2,3], [3,6,7]];
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var count = 0;

combosArr.forEach(e => {
if(e.every(r => arr1.includes(r)))
  count++;
})
if(count == combosArr.length)
  console.log(combosArr);
```

Comment: This didn't worked for 
```let combosArr = [[1,2,3], [3,6,7]];```

Comment: I changed the answer now, @DeepakTerse

Comment: Well, it still got some issues. Not working for ```let combosArr = [[1,2,3], [3,6,9]];```

Comment: Btw, I did got the working solution for this. Please check

Comment: @DeepakTerse Yes, that's the idea. He asked that "if arr1 doesn't have all the elements from one of the arrays in combosArr it mustn't console.log it"

Comment: It should not print for let combosArr = [[1,2,3], [3,6,9]];

Comment: Oh! Then its okay

Comment: added an alternative, in the case he wants to print array by array